# ForEach loop but using a generic list as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Well I've made a display method and it's a list so what I'm trying to do with no success is getting it to display it but I'm not able to as it's running into the CS1503 error which I'm unable to figure out and I'm just after some guidance on the matter/solution.

I end up with the error occurring in Class B in the foreach loop at `manageAccounts.DispalyBasicInfo(item);`

I'm only still learning C#.

Class A:

```
public void DisplayBasicInfo(List<Account> lstAcc)
{
    foreach (var item in lstAcc)
    {
        Account objAccTemp = item;
        lblCustomerName.Text = objAccTemp.CustomerName;
        lblCustomerNo.Text = objAccTemp.AccountID.ToString();
        if (objAccTemp.AccountType != null)
        {
            lstAccounts.Items.Add(objAccTemp.AccountID + " " + objAccTemp.AccountType + " $" + objAccTemp.BankBalance);
        }
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
private void btnManageAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ManageAccounts manageAccounts = new ManageAccounts();
        string strTemp = lstCustomers.SelectedItem.ToString();
        foreach (var item in Controller.lstAccounts)
        {
            if (item.CustomerName == strTemp)
            {
                manageAccounts.DisplayBasicInfo(item);
            }
        }
        manageAccounts.Show();
        Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a customer or create one", "No Selection");
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of people are not able to convert error codes into meaningful error messages in their heads, please share full error text. Definitions of all relevant variables would be helpful, too.

Comment: You are hiding important parts of code like what is the DataSources for your listboxes. Anyway, at least your item is not a List<Account>, is it.

Comment: Please, since you are learning, try to avoid this insane `try`/`catch (Exception)` pattern. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle. You should certainly not do it for program flow, which is what you're doing.

Comment: `DisplayBasicInfo` expects `List<Account>` as its only argument. In the second code snippet you access `item.CustomerName` and then pass `item` into `DisplayBasicInfo`. Since `List<T>` don't have `CustomerName` property, I can deduce that `item` is not of type `List<T>`, which compiler likely complains about.

Comment: It would be great if you could post your entire source code. You're doing some things that are all over the place, that I think is making your code difficult to read and then difficult to reason about and then difficult to maintain. I'd like to be able to refactor it to show you what might be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DisplayBasicInfo()` method expects an entire list:

```
public void DisplayBasicInfo(List<Account> lstAcc)
```

But when you call it, you don't have a list. You only have a single account:

```
manageAccounts.DisplayBasicInfo(item);
```

Additionally, if you did pass a whole list to method, only **last item** would show on the screen, since the loop overwrites the same items on every iteration.

Therefore you probably want this:

```
public void DisplayBasicInfo(Account account)
{
    lblCustomerName.Text = account.CustomerName;
    lblCustomerNo.Text = account.AccountID.ToString();
    if (account.AccountType != null)
    {
        lstAccounts.Items.Add($"{account.AccountID} {account.AccountType} {account.BankBalance:C2}";
    }
}
```

Last of all, I don't know who's teaching you to use prefixes like `lst` or `obj`, but that's no longer recommended. It made sense back in the old days, but now tooling has improved. Even Microsoft, where the practice was created, now specifically publishes style guidelines asking people not to use this notation.

Comment: Thank you very much and it has fixed the problem I've had. The person teaching me is my lecturer who still says that this is the way to do it so I'll have a look at the Microsoft Style Guidelines.

Comment: Nope. Those prefixes have been dead for more than a decade. The only place they're still used is for WinForms controls (txt, lbl, ddl, etc). See here in the official .Net naming guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions